# Looping through df with 3 columns using iterrows, but getting error that says there are only 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iterator

I have a df structured as such:

```
                T1                  T2                 T3
14577 2016-01-01 06:55:18 2016-01-01 06:58:00 2016-01-01 07:03:58
14578 2016-01-01 08:25:29 2016-01-01 08:29:02 2016-01-01 08:50:23
14579 2016-01-01 10:38:55 2016-01-01 10:40:00 2016-01-01 11:06:43
14580 2016-01-01 13:38:05 2016-01-01 13:45:23 2016-01-01 13:51:47
...
```

I then try to iterate through each row as such:

```
for i,j,k in df.iterrows():
    print(i,j,k)
```

But I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-66-b6aadd823294>", line 1, in <module>
for i,j,k in df.iterrows():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Just to be clear, here are the dimensions of df:

```
>>>df.shape
Out[68]: 
(434, 3)
```

Comment: `df.iterrows` returns the index and the row not the columns hence the error, if you want to iterate over the columns and print them then do `for col in df: print(df[col])`

Comment: Well, that makes me feel stupid. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.iterrows() would iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs ([source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)). The series would contain the whole row.

You can try this inorder to print the values

```
for row, series in df.iterrows():
    print(series['T1'], series['T2'],series['T3'])
```